# Html.RenderComponentPresenationsByView returns JSON

Tags: 2013, dd4t, 2013-sp1

I have two pages. Both pages have the same component and CT set up on them. I publish them both to my staging site. The first page renders just fine. The second page does not. The second page when I call:

```
 @Html.RenderComponentPresentationsByView("SocialLinks")
```

It returns the JSON of the published component.

The first page has this same line of code and it hits my controller code just fine.

I have turned on logging to "Debug" level and nothing really helpful in there. Here is the info from the log I could find that referenced my component Id.

```
2016-07-19 12:52:35,781 DEBUG ComponentLink - ComponentLink.getLinkInfo(): read all published components for component 2139
2016-07-19 12:52:35,781 DEBUG ComponentLink - ComponentLink Could not find metadata for page: 0
2016-07-19 12:52:35,781 DEBUG ComponentLink - ComponentLink.getLink(): start retrieving pathinfo for this page: 0
2016-07-19 12:52:35,781 DEBUG ComponentLink - Found component with score 2147483647
2016-07-19 12:52:35,781 INFO  ComponentLink - ComponentLink.getLink(): couldn't create a link to any other instance of component presentation 2139:0 from page 0
2016-07-19 12:52:35,781 DEBUG LRUPolicy - LRUModel: listSize = 134  memSize = 10888197
2016-07-19 12:52:35,781 DEBUG CacheController - Adding a dependency from Object [19:2139] in Region [/com_tridion_linking_ComponentLinkInfo] to Object [false:false:19:0:2139:0::] in Region [/com.tridion.linking.ComponentLink]
2016-07-19 12:52:35,781 DEBUG CacheController - Adding a dependency from Object [19:0] in Region [/com.tridion.broker.pages.meta.PageMeta] to Object   [false:false:19:0:2139:0::] in Region [/com.tridion.linking.ComponentLink]

2016-07-19 12:51:36,967 DEBUG LRUPolicy - Removing node with key false:false:19:0:2139:0::
2016-07-19 12:51:36,967 DEBUG LRUPolicy - Removing node with key 19:2139

2016-07-19 12:53:22,895 DEBUG CacheChannel - Received event from another VM [CacheEvent eventType=Invalidate regionPath=/com.tridion.storage.ReferenceEntry key=19:tcd:pub[19]/componentmeta[2139]:tcd:pub[19]/pagemeta[58564]]


2016-07-19 12:53:23,082 DEBUG CacheChannel - Received event from another VM [CacheEvent eventType=Invalidate regionPath=/com.tridion.storage.ItemMeta key=19:2139]
```

I am on DD4T 2.0 and Tridion 2013 SP1. Sorry not a lot to go on but this is killing me so hoping someone has seen it before?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I gather, you have Page 1 rendering just fine, but Page 2 simply prints out the JSON of the Component Presentation without hitting the CP controller nor view.

Could it be that the Page Templates for the two pages are different? The one that is not working could possibly have the logic to print out the JSON instead of calling the CP controller and views.